# Issues with large POST request

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a bug in an AJAX request that only happens with large JSON objects.

I'm using the JSON object of a canvas that has drawings on it (rectangles, lines, freedraw, etc).  When the user is done and wants to save it for later they save it and go about other business.  I'm having an issue when the drawing is exceptionally large that either the POST won't hit the controller method.

I've added multiple config settings to my web.config including:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090" />
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
```

All of which have no solved the problem; the code for the request is as follows.

```
$('#submitSketch').click(function () {
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(lc.getSnapshot());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("SaveSketch")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#currLevelId").val(), jsonString: jsonString })
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert("Saved");
                })
                .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
                    alert("Unable to save!");
                });
            });
```

The Header of the method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSketch(int id, string jsonString)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Just a 500

POST http://localhost:59394/Job/SaveSketch
500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.js:7978
(anonymous function) @ 70:147
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.js:2750

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Errors are now on the question

Comment: You should be able to get a much better info by inspecting the Ajax request from your browser. You should see exactly what the server returns to you.

Comment: Use visual studio break points ! 500 error means your code is crashing

Comment: There's a break point on the first line of the method; it's breaking before it.

Comment: I feel like there is either a hard string limit on stringify, or a heap limit on the json object in memory. Can someone confirm?

Comment: I've verified that the stringify is getting the entire string; I run a copy statement in the console and paste it into an editor and it's the entire object.
As a side note; the breaking point seems to be around 2 million characters.

Comment: Your controller method is expecting 2 different items, but you are sending only one object. I think it might work better if you create a class that has an int id and string jsonstring and then have that one object as the only parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are encountering this issue because you params are incorrect. You are sending one object from the browser, but your Controller method is expecting two properties.

Try creating a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string jsonString {get;set;
}
```

and then update your controller method to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSketch(MyClass myClass)
```

Comment: That's definitely a better way to do it; and I'll keep it as such. But unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: I don't think you need to do data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#currLevelId").val(), jsonString: jsonString }); you should be able to just do this: data: { id: $("#currLevelId").val(), jsonString: jsonString }
If you are still receiving the 500 error, then most likely the serialization isn't matching what the controller is expecting. If you put a breakpoint on the first line of that Conrtoller method, does it get hit?

Comment: No, but I put an application_error catch in global.asax and the error coming through is: "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property." So for some reason it's not respecting the value I set in the .config file.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue is that the project wasn't respecting the value for maxJsonLength I had set in my config file.

Workaround can be found at the following site:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1751116.aspx?How+to+increase+maxJsonLength+for+JSON+POST+in+MVC3